# The value cannot be converted to a number

Tags: coldfusion

Got a critical error like: The value cannot be converted to a number. what can be the problem? Since i tried to write this values like:

```
1. <cfset ortalama=trim(val(db_maliyet_temp))+ds_toplam_maliyet>

2. <cfset ortalama=val(db_maliyet_temp)+ds_toplam_maliyet>

3. <cfset ortalama=db_maliyet_temp+ds_toplam_maliyet>
```

the first and second are just doesnt count the db_maliyet_temp,
and the 3 give out the error: The value cannot be converted to a number.

Comment: What are the values of db_maliyet_temp and ds_toplam_maliyet? Are you trying to concatenate text or add numbers?

Comment: Also, what version of CF are you using?

Comment: @Quickfire55 i dont know exactly what is the version of coldfusion, but i can say, that i concentrate on adding numbers, btw the db_maliyet_temp and ds_toplam_maliyet are displayed as the numbers, but i just can't add them

Comment: You're either concatenating OR adding. Can you please post an example of the value(s) of db_maliyet_temp and ds_toplam_maliyet? Also I still need to know whether you're adding or concat'ing. Adding example: 2 + 2 = 4. Concat: 2 & 2 = 22.

Comment: @Quickfire55 im trying to add them not to concat :)

Comment: OK, post their values :)

Comment: @Quickfire55 value for db_maliyet_temp: 2.806,71 for ds_toplam_maliyet: 394,22

Comment: @user745110 - Next time post an example of the values up front. If we had been able to see a sample .. someone would have spotted the problem (european number format) immediately ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> value for db_maliyet_temp: 2.806,71
>   for ds_toplam_maliyet: 394,22

These are not valid numbers. If you would like the total of the numbers, you can try this.

```
<cfset aryMaliyetNumbers = ListToArray(db_maliyet_temp, ",")>
<cfset aryToplamNumbers = ListToArray(ds_toplam_maliyet, ",")>
<cfset total = ArraySum(aryMaliyetNumbers) + ArraySum(aryToplamNumbers)>
```

There are several ways to skin this cat. This should at least get you going. Works perfectly on my CF 7 box!

**EDIT**

After the ridiculous amount of comments to clarify the question, I believe this is the solution.

```
<cfset db_maliyet_temp = Replace(Replace("2.806,71", ".", ""), ",", ".")>
<cfset ds_toplam_maliyet = Replace(Replace("394,22", ".", ""), ",", ".")>
<cfset total = db_maliyet_temp + ds_toplam_maliyet>
```

If you want the number without decimals, you can do this:

```
<cfset db_maliyet_temp = Replace(Replace("2.806,71", ".", ""), ",", ".")>
<cfset ds_toplam_maliyet = Replace(Replace("394,22", ".", ""), ",", ".")>
<cfset total = val(db_maliyet_temp + ds_toplam_maliyet)>
```

**IMPORTANT**

You have a much larger problem than a CF error. You need to fix the underlying issue that's causing your number to be formatted incorrectly.

Comment: Are you saying that you ran it and the sum was 468.021407, or that's what you're expecting? I'm looking at the results on my CF 7 box and I got 489.806.

Comment: @Quickfire55 it seems that it count the comma as the delimiter, that is why its adding the instead of 2.806,71 the number 71 :)

Comment: @Quickfire55 but i need to get 3.200,93

Comment: I'm totally confused. The comma IS a delimiter. 2.806,71 is not a valid number. The above logic splits your delimited strings into 4 numbers and sums them. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: @Quickfire55 to get from 2.806,71 and 394,22 the sum 3.200,93

Comment: I ALMOST understand. 71 + 22 = 93. I get that. I can update the code accordingly. Where are you getting 3.2? 2.806 + 394 = 396.806?

Comment: @Quickfire55 this is not 2.806 this is 2 thousand eight hundred and six :) and the 394.22 is three hundred ninety four point twenty two

Comment: @Quickfire55 i know these numbers are written in the wrong way, that is why the error comes :) that is why im asking to add them up in a way i want ))

Comment: So the numbers need corrected first? In the future you need to may your questions MUCH more clear!

Comment: if it is possible, maybe there is a way to add them in an other way

Comment: i just didnt expect them to be wrongly written :) just thought its ok till we had misunderstanding ))

Comment: there is a long list of code to get these values, they are changed to arrays and strings and vice versa many times, so that's why :) i didnt write this code, just need to modify it...

Comment: See above edit. For the love of all that is good, please vote up and mark as answer!

Comment: That is standard european number formatting... so you really want to look at doing the conversion before it goes into the DB, but since you have legacy data it might be worth cleaning it all up before you start doing that.

Comment: @Daniel, he said they were messed up because of all the preprocessing. But you're correct.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
<cfscript>
    function convertToNumber(num){
          return reReplace(reReplace(num,'.','','ALL'),',','.','ALL');
    }
</cfscript>

<cfset ortalama=convertToNumber(db_maliyet_temp)+convertToNumber(ds_toplam_maliyet)>
```

Basically it just removes the '.' since that is formatting not needed for math and replaces the ',' with a decimal so that it can be treated as a number. This will only work if ALL the numbers you are going to be dealing with are formatted this way, if there are any formatted like 1,200.90 then you will have to be a little more fancy.

Comment: I suspect you meant `replace` rather than `reReplace`, because the above will return an empty string ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the LSParseNumber() function?:

http://cfquickdocs.com/cf9/#lsparsenumber

Or the val() function?:

http://cfquickdocs.com/cf9/#val

Also, it may be easier to clean the data before it get's entered either with client-side validation (if it's coming from a form) or server-side validation.